# O(n*log(n)) = O(log(n!))?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-nlogn)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) states that O(n*log(n)) = O(log(n!)). I don't quite get why. Can anybody explain or prove why it is that way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-nlogn) and [Lower bound for sorting by comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233553/lowed-bound-for-sorting-by-comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the page on [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)